# Solving $dS^x(t)=S^x(t)(r(t)dt+\gamma(t,S^x(t))dW(t))$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the stochastic process $S^x(t)$ with $S^x(0)=x$ $$dS^x(t)=S^x(t)(r(t)dt+\gamma(t,S^x(t))dW(t))$$and define $D^x(t)=(\partial/\partial x)S^x(t)$. Then $$dD^x(t)=D^x(t)\Big[r(t)dt+\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\rho(t,S^x(t))dW(t)\Big]$$ ($W$ is a 1-d Brownian motion)and therefore, $$D^x(t)=exp\Big[\int_0^tr(u)du\Big]exp\Big[\int_0^t \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\rho(u,S^x(u))dW(u)-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\Big( \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\rho(u,S^x(u))\Big)^2du\Big]$$

where $\rho (t,s):=s\gamma(t,s)$. All the above I have been able to derive by myself. I need help proving the following identity. $$\frac{S^y(t)-S^x(t)}{M(t)}=y-x+\int_0^t \frac{1}{M(u)}[\rho(u,S^y(u))-\rho(u,S^x(u))]dW(u)$$

where $M(t)=exp[\int_0^t r(u)du]$

I was wondering if the best way is to find the integral of $D^x$ w.r.t $x$ which gives $$S^y(t)-S^x(t)=\int_x^yD(z)dz$$

However, this seems too complicated. Is there a better way or can this integral be evaluated? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Itô's formula, we have

$$f(t) X(t) - f(0) X(0) = \int_0^t f(s) \, dX(s) + \int_0^t X(s) f'(s) \, ds \tag{1}$$

for any Itô process $(X_t)_t$ and any function $f \in C_b^1(\mathbb{R})$. Using this identity for $$f(t) := \exp \left(- \int_0^t r(u) \, du \right) \quad \text{and} \quad X(t) := S^x(t)$$ we get

\begin{align*} \exp\left(-\int_0^t r(u) \, du\right) S^x(t) - x &= \int_0^t \exp\left(-\int_0^s r(u) \, du\right) \, dS^x(s) \\& \quad - \int_0^t r(s) \exp\left(-\int_0^s r(u) \, du\right) S^x(s) \, ds. \end{align*}

As $$dS^x(s) = S^x(s) r(s) \, ds + S^x(s) \gamma(s,S^x(s)) \, dW(s)$$

by the very definition of $(S^x(t))_{t \geq 0}$, this gives

\begin{align*} \exp\left(-\int_0^t r(u) \, du\right) S^x(t) - x &= \int_0^t \exp \left(- \int_0^s r(u) \, du \right) S^x(s) \gamma(s,S^x(s)) \, dW(s)  \tag{2} \end{align*}

i.e.

$$\frac{1}{M_t} S^x(t)-x = \int_0^t \frac{1}{M(s)} \varrho(s,S^x(s)) \, dW(s)$$ where we have set $$M(t) = \exp \left( \int_0^t r(u) \, du \right) \quad \text{and} \quad \varrho(s,x) := s \gamma(s,x).$$

Since $(2)$ holds for any initial point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we conclude that

$$\frac{1}{M_t} (S^y(t)-S^x(t)) = y-x + \int_0^t \frac{1}{M(s)} \left( \varrho(s,S^y(s))-\varrho(s,S^x(s) \right) \, dW(s).$$

Comment: @Heisenberg Well, yes, if you want to put it like this. I was rather thinking of [this version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma#It%C3%B4_drift-diffusion_processes_(due_to:_Kunita%E2%80%93Watanabe)) of Itô's formula. (Obviously, you will end up with the same result if you apply Itô's product rule... in the end, Itô's product rule is a particular case of Itô's formula.)

Comment: The first formula is Ito's product rule right?

Comment: I tried using the Ito's rule to $\ln(S^x(t))$ but for some reason I could not get the desired answer

Comment: @Heisenberg There is no $\ln$ in my answer... why would you want to apply Itô's rule to this function?

Comment: $d(\ln(S^x(t)))=r(t)dt+\gamma dW(t)-{1/2}{\gamma}^2 dt$ and then you take the integral of both sides. So you end up with $\ln(S^x(t)/x)=...$ and the take $e$

Comment: @Heisenberg ... but to which end...? I don't understand what you are trying to prove/do. I explained in my answer how to derive the identity which you were interested in... but as I already mentioned in my previous comment you don't need any logarithms here.

Comment: Yes your answer works. thanks